# Is this a correct implementation of ConvertsWithoutNarrowing

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-concepts

I am currently learning about concepts in C++20, and came across this example:

```
template <typename From, typename To>
concept is_convertible_without_narrowing = requires (From&& from) {
  { std::type_identity_t<To[]>{std::forward<From>(from)}} -> std::same_as<To[1]>;
};
```

I am curious if the following can be considered a correct alternative implementation of the above:

```
template <typename From, typename To>
concept is_convertible_without_narrowing = requires (From&& from) {
  { To{std::forward<From>(from)} } -> std::same_as<To>;
}
```

or, even simpler:

```
template <typename From, typename To>
concept is_convertible_without_narrowing = requires (From&& from, To&& to) {
  to = {from};
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I am curious if the following can be considered a correct alternative
> implementation of the above:

The simple answer is no.

In the second version, `To{std::forward<From>(from)}` can be regarded as  constructing `To` through `initializer_list`, so `is_convertible_without_narrowing<int, std::vector<int>>` will be `true`.

Similarly, the third version can be regarded as assigning `To` with `initializer_list`, so `is_convertible_without_narrowing<int, std::vector<int>&>` will also be `true`.